# How to install a latest / unstable Haskell package executable in Nixos?

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm trying to get the latest version of `ghcid` installed.

I've installed `ghcid` via adding `haskellPackages.ghcid` in my nix config like so:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let
  unstable = import <unstable> {};
in
{
   environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
     haskellPackages.ghcid
   ];
}
```

---

I thought possibly it would be available as a specific package but I can't seem to find anything:

```
nix-env -v -qaP haskellPackages.ghcid
```

And

```
nix-env -v -qaP ghcid
```

Return `...matches no derivations`

Comment: I recommend adding developer tools like `ghcid` to the project's `shell.nix`, if that works well for your use case. Nonetheless, this *is* a valid approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly simple:

```
 unstable.haskellPackages.ghcid
```